# How can I attach an entity to the context when one of its children is already attached?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1

**Background**

In my application we were running into issues when trying to add a new entity with existing children to the database after mapping it from a DTO using AutoMapper. The entity and its children were not attached to the context, and so the children would be treated as new and EF would attempt to insert duplicates. My solution to this was to automatically attach an entity to the context whenever an object was mapped to a BaseEntity type (BaseEntity is the base class for all of our Model objects, it has an Id property and nothing else). Here is the code:

```
public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source) where TDestination : class
{
    var result = _mapper.Map<TDestination>(source);
    if (typeof(TDestination).IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)) && result != null)
        _context.Attach(result); //_context is a DbContext
    return result;
}
```

This worked fine in my initial test cases, but now I've run into an issue where the entity I'm attaching has a child that is already attached to the context. This throws "The instance of entity type 'MyChildEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.".

How can I attach an entity to the context when a child is already attached? I'm trying to keep this method extremely generic so that it can be used by any object that we are trying to map from a DTO to a BaseEntity.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried grabbing the associated EntityEntry and recursively detach all of its children using the following method before attempting to call Attach():

```
private void DetachChildren(EntityEntry entity)
{
    foreach (var member in entity.Members.Where(x => x.CurrentValue != null))
    {
        if (IsBaseEntityType(member.CurrentValue.GetType()))
        {
            var childEntity = _context.Entry(member.CurrentValue);
            childEntity.State = EntityState.Detached;
            DetachChildren(childEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that this loop does reach the problem child and sets its state to detached, but I still end up getting the same error when calling Attach().

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem, but if you really need to do what you're saying you'll need to de-attach any existing entities with the same id first using the changeTracker.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the hell that is working with detached entities.

Automapper can be leveraged to update existing entities rather than forming an entity and attaching it. Given an object like an Order:

```
public void UpdateOrder(OrderDTO orderDTO)
{
    var order = _context.Orders.Single(x => x.OrderId = orderDTO.OrderId);
    _mapper.Map(orderDTO, order);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The benefits of this approach is that it handles whether the order happens to be tracked or not, asserts the order exists for something like an Update where it is assumed it does, and when SaveChanges runs, only the fields that actually changed will be updated. If only 1 field changed, the update statement updates that single field. Attaching a new object and setting EntityState to Modified will update *all* fields. This could introduce unexpected attack vectors to change data you don't expect since a DTO needs to pass enough info to construct a whole entity to avoid unintentionally #null-ing data. The mapping from DTO to entity should ensure that only editable fields are copied across.

In the case where the OrderDTO will contain one or more child collections to update, you will likely need to use a mapping that *excludes* those collections, then use `AfterMap` in the mapping configuration to inspect the child collection for new vs. existing vs. removed entities and handle those accordingly. (`Add` vs. `mapper.Map` vs. `Remove`)

Generally the updates can be structured to perform atomic operations that make the entity interactions as straight forward as possible. For instance UpdateOrderDetails(orderDTO) would update information about the order itself, where there would be separate methods such as AddOrderLine(newOrderLineDTO) vs.  UpdateOrderLine(orderLineDTO) vs. RemoveOrderLine(orderLineId)  etc. rather than having all order line operations and other related changes done through a single UpdateOrder method accepting a whole modified object graph.

The alternative when dealing with graphs and the possibility of tracked entities is that you need to check each and every related entity against the DbSet's `.Local` or other means to check to see if the entity is tracked. If it is, then you have to replace the references and copy any applicable changes to the already tracked entity. Telling a DbContext to ignore an existing entity isn't always a simple matter as there can be references to that entity in other tracked entities. Generally you'll want to detect a tracked entity reference then update your references to use that tracked reference and update it as needed. It is lots of mucking around with references, and definitely does *not* work well with Generic methods

Generic operations are tempting from a DNRY standpoint, but dealing with situations where some entities might be tracked vs. not, and then handling type mismatches etc. (source = `object` = can be anything..) adds a lot of complexity in place of simpler methods to handle operations.